# Timestamp for specific property - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, timestamp

I need to get timestamp for last time property "published" goes from 'false' to 'true' or vice versa, and I need to have createdAt, and updatedAt properties. So, I pass timestamps: true, to Mongoose model configuration and everything if fine with createdAt and updatedAt propertios.

I dont know, so I need your help, how to get timestamp for properties publishedAt and unpublishedAt. Here is my Mongoose model, where you can see everything.

If you need any additional information just write im comments section.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const offerSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 255
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 255
    },
    published: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    publishedAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    unpublishedAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    introduction: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    authorId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    sectionId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Section'
    }
},  {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Offer', offerSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

That thing you want is too custom and Mongoose don't provide such function out of the box.

But that is not the problem, because you can implement it yourself. You can use `pre` hook to run some custom code and then every time you update a field you are interested in, update the timestamp.